# Magento subcategory display on click parent

Tags: magento

I have created my own `parent.phtml` page in Magento to display a grid view on the home page and it is working.

My question is about clicking a parent category and then displaying all subcategories grid like `subcategory.phtml`.  How do I set my URL which passes the parent id in the URL and redirect to `subcategory.phtml`? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this `http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-subcategories-category-pages`. It redirects to page displaying sub-categories along with images on clicking the main category.

Comment: This work fine but magento by default block also disply subcategory so two time repeate all sub category.

Comment: Dint understand what are you saying.How is it displaying twice?

Comment: two times subacategory display when i set in category like static block only the already one time disply and after when choose my cms block the second time call all sub category

Comment: Due to image not available,Image is displaying category name as alternate.

Comment: If you do not need the image then you can remove that image part or just make its display none.

Comment: Or if you want the image then upload thumbnail and images for that category through the upload option.